# How can I automatically convert a field in lowercase to uppercase in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have produced some VBA code to resolve this problem :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Value <> Empty Then
      Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
   End If
End Sub
```

But when I try to input some data in a field, Excel stops working without a single error message.

Does anyone know where this problem can come from ?

Comment: The funny thing is that the code works before Excel stops...

Comment: Did you set the enableEvents to false?  Otherwhise, it would self trigger again (or any other eventHandler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have set Application.EnableEvents = False. Open the Immediate window in the VBA editor and type in `application.EnableEvents = True` then ENTER to turn them back on.

Also, you need to disable events if you don't want to cause a cycle of changing the sheet and re-triggering the event. The ISEMPTY function is slightly different in VBA and your code could be updated to the following which will also handle changing more than just 1 cell

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Variant

        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each cell In Target
                If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                   cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
                End If
           Next cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

or if you want to restrict this running to 1 cell change only, replace the for each loop with `If Target.rows.count = 1 AND Target.columns.count = 1....`

Comment: In the complete code, i did this : If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And (Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 4)... But you might be right, there is probably a cycle of triggering the event, I check this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the callback function in the right spot:

From [Events And Event Procedures In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

> For sheet (both worksheet and chart sheet) level events, the event procedure code must be placed in the Sheet module associated with that sheet. Workbook level events must be placed in the ThisWorkbook code module. If an event procedure is not in the proper module, VBA will not be able to find it and the event code will not be executed.

Comment: Actually it is in the right spot, i put it in the "This Worbook" MSExcel Object so it applies to all the workbook, not only in something like the 1st worksheet.

Anyway, I've tried to put it where you said, in a blank Excel project, and it didn't work either